# Change line spaces on horizontal description list <dl>

Tags: html, css, list

I've created a description list where the titles and data are on the same line (http://jsfiddle.net/ajkuwwsc/)

[image]

I would like to add space between Row Two and Row Three (and not all the rows which I am able to do), and make EMAIL line up with the email address and icon.

My attempt to add space between rows two and three was not successful! (http://jsfiddle.net/ajkuwwsc/1/).  I am not sure how to pull up the email to be in line.

How is this accomplished?

[image]

```
dl {
    width: 395px;
    font-size:12px
}
dd, dt {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
dt {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
dt {
    clear: left;
}
dt, dd {
    min-height:1.5em;
}
/* .more-space{padding-bottom:20px;} */

<dl>
    <dt>Row 1:</dt>
    <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bla bla bla</a></dd>
    <dt class="more-space">Row Two:</dt>
    <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more-space">Bla bla bla Bla bla bla</a></dd>
    <dt>Row Three (3):</dt>
    <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bla bla</a></dd>
    <dt>EMAIL:</dt>
    <dd>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Marilyn.Adams@example.com</a>
        <a href="mailto:Marilyn.Adams@example.com"><img title="Send Email" src="http://s8.postimg.org/85a36p329/messages.png" alt="Send Email"></a>
    </dd>
    <dt>Row 5:</dt>
    <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bla bla</a></dd>
    <dt>Empty Row:</dt>
    <dd></dd>
    <dt>Row 6:</dt>
    <dd><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bla</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: So is your goal trying to make the email row line up properly?

Comment: @Huangism  Yes, and make rows 2 and three a bit further apart.

Comment: I feel that this is the perfect spot to actually use a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D Table columns are the same so it won't work.  And then you get into that whole table debate!

Comment: Nothing wrong with tables in the right place and this looks like tabluar data. You may not be able to maintain the same structure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the alignment of the image that's causing an issue in the first instance. You can fix that by giving it a `vertical-align` value of `middle`

```
img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[More information on `vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

For the spacing, rather than creating a new class (which, incidentally, you were only applying to the `dt` and not the `dd` that followed), you can target the items you want to create space beneath using the `:nth-of-type` pseudo class.

```
dt:nth-of-type(2),dd:nth-of-type(2){
    margin:0 0 20px;
}
```

[More information on `:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: Ah, `vertical-align`.  Let me try it out.  In regards to spacing, so use margin instead of padding?

Comment: Either-or for the spacing in this instance. `padding` will create extra space within the element, while `margin` will create extra space outside the element. For spacing between items, I have preference for `margin`.

Comment: Perfect for both.  Thank you.  My problem with spacing is I accidentally put the class on the `<a>` instead of the `<dd>`.  I find it odd that I need to apply it to two elements, but guess that is just the way stuff works.